# How to Rewrite urls if not ends with language id or country id in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to Rewrite urls if not ends  with language id or country id in .htaccess

in my case i want redirect links not ends with

`home/(en | fr| ar)/(us| ma |ae | sa  )`

for exemple :

`https://exemple.com/home/en/sa/...`

`https://exemple.com/home/es/sa/...`

`https://exemple.com/home/ar/...`

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^home/!(en|ae|sa)/!(sa|ma|ae|sa)/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

but it didn't work

Thank you all

Comment: What should be these URLs be redirected to?

Comment: if contain "home" should redirect to link without 'home '

for exemple: 
ftom : https://exemple.com/home/en/ad/37/test-test
to : https://exemple.com/en/ad/37/test-test

"home" is only for switching country and language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^home/(?!(?:en|fr|ar)/(?:us|ma|ae|sa))([^/]+/[^/]+) /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

`(?!(?:en|fr|ar)/(?:us|ma|ae|sa))` is a negative lookahead condition that will fail the URL match if `/home` is not followed by allowed `language/country` codes.

Comment: I tried it  but  /home/en redirect to  /en.
I don't want to redirect links that end with:

`/home/en/qa `     Or
`/home/en/`

Comment: Sir , there are cases in which it does not work
for exemple : `https://exemple.com/home/category/emploi-et-services` not redirect to `https://exemple.com/category/emploi-et-services`

Comment: ok try my updated rule again